# Set SQL SERVER Express 2017 to allow remote connections

Tags: sql-server

Just recovering my server from a major crash, which led to windows server 2016 being re-installed...

I have a desktop application which connects to the sql server database, trouble is now I have the database setup on the server I cant remember how to make it available to external sources (the application)

Can you help?

Comment: Well, one thing - very often overlooked - is to open the standard firewall. SQL Server does not do that itself ;)

Comment: And you have to enable TCP/IP access as well (using SQL Server Configuration Manager), I guess. I think it is disabled by default.

Comment: Can you connect _locally_? What error are you getting when you try and connect remotely?

Comment: the message I get is  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following steps to enable remote connections to your SQL Server,

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Right-click your server's name and select Properties.
3. Select  Connections option
4. Tick the checkbox "Allow remote connections to this server."
5. Select OK.

**Enable TCP/IP and Open 1433 port**

1. Take SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Select SQLServer network Configuration->Protocols for MSSQLServer
3. In the right-hand pane,make sure that TCP/IP is Enabled.
4. Right click on TCP/IP and select the Properties option.
5. In the TCP/IP Properties dialog select the IP Addresses tab and scroll down to IPAII.
6. Make sure that the TCP Port is 1433.

   **Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access**
7. Take Windows Administrative tools
8. From Administrative Tools select the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security option
9. In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog, click on the Inbound Rules option and select the New Rule command
10. In the New Inbound Rule wizard select the Port option and click Next
11. In the Protocols and Ports window specify the protocols and ports to which a rule applies. Select the TCP option, in the Specific local ports text box enter the 1433 port, and click Next
12. In the Action window select the Allow the connection to specify the action to be taken when a connection matches the conditions specified in the rule
13. Specify the profiles for which the rule applies in the Profile window, and click Next
14. In the last window specify the name of the created rule and click the Finish button

**Configure remote access on a named instance of SQL Server**

1. Take Windows Administrative tools
2. From Administrative Tools select Windows Firewall with Advanced Security option
3. In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog, click on the Inbound Rules option and select the New Rule command
4. In the New Inbound Rule wizard select the Port option and click Next
5. In the Protocols and Ports window specify the protocols and ports to which a rule applies. Select the TCP option, in the Specific local ports text box enter the 1433 port, and click Next
6. In the Action window select the Allow the connection to specify the action to be taken when a connection matches the conditions specified in the rule
7. Specify the profiles for which the rule applies in the Profile window, and click Next
8. In the last window specify the name of the created rule and click the Finish button

Comment: Nice. Still, your 3rd and 4th categories are identical. I assume you need to have the remote source running a compatible version of SQL Server and maybe a fixed IP address? Shouldn't the Backend server know the IP address of the client? Sorry if I am lost. I mean, how else do we know who to allow into the firewall? And shouldn't the source/client also know the IP address of the backend to be able to even log in? And how do we create users and roles categories for the client?

Answer (score 2):

For any of you using Named instances (or SQL Express) you need to also open up UDP port 1434.  Here are command lines I used instead of the above UI process.

To Open TCP (SQL Server and SQL Browser):

```
NETSH advFirewall firewall add rule name="Allow: Inbound: TCP: SQL Server Services" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1433,1434,2382
```

To Open UDP (SQL Server Dynamic for Named and SQLEXPRESS):

```
NETSH advFirewall firewall add rule name="Allow: Inbound: TCP: SQL Server Services Dyn" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=1434
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Express and did not find these extra ports to be necessary.