# How to solve “SqlClient connection fails when ran in Docker Desktop”?

Tags: c#, docker, sql-server-express, sqlclient

I'm attempting to connect to a local SQL Server Express instance I have on my dev box.

I'm using the following code:

```
var cs = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
cs.InitialCatalog = "dev_db";
cs.DataSource = @"(local)\SQLEXPRESS";
cs.IntegratedSecurity = false;
cs.ConnectTimeout = 5;
cs.Encrypt = false;
cs.UserID = "user";
cs.Password = "password";

var xpto = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs.ConnectionString);
xpto.Open();
```

This works fine in a console or Windows app, but fails miserably when trying in a Web API project running in a Docker Desktop (configured as Linux).

The exact same code.

This is the exception thrown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the  instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Has anyone encountered this problem and know how to solve it?

To preemptively answer questions:

1. I also followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298469) to configure SQL Server Express.
2. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662), I tried using `host.docker.internal` and using the IP address of my dev box. Both tries yielded the same results.

```
// Attempt with host.docker.internal
cs.DataSource = @"host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS"; 
// Same error

// Attempt with dev box IP
cs.DataSource = @"192.168.15.3\SQLEXPRESS";
// Same error.
```

3. The instance of SQL Server Express is on the dev box, not in the Docker.
4. SQL Server Express is configured to allow remote connections:

[image: SQLExpress configuration]

Edited to add:

This is the Docker file:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestProject.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./TestProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "TestProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProject.dll"]
```

Edited to add:

Connection with a PostgreSQL database was successful. Only SQL Server Express is giving me a headache.

Comment: Try disabling Windows Firewall (just as a test).

Comment: Is it `SQLEXPRESS` running on your docker container or it is on your local machine?

Comment: Can you show us your docker file? What ports do you have open on your docker container?

Comment: Since docker is a separate networking layer, you may need to explicitly open the SQL Server port in the Windows firewall.

Comment: Did you forward the ports into the SQL Server container using `-p realport:containerport`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama .... mmmm .... no. How do I do this?

Comment: _"I tried using host.docker.internal and using the IP"_ - Please show the attempt with. What connection string you have tried to provide for docker instance?

Comment: Wait are you running your SQL Server instance in Docker?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama no. The SQLEXpress is in the dev box. The Docker is clean.

Comment: @GuruStron Added my different attempts.

Comment: @PauloSantos try defining full connection string. Check out [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), so the attempt should be something like: `cs.DataSource = @"Server=host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"`